# Autenticação em um website para visualização de relatórios do Power BI

Tags: api, autenticação, powerbi

É possível fazer um login no meu site e utilizar o *username* (ou e-mail) e *password* para logar automaticamente no Power BI, criando uma sessão ou utilizando alguma API?

Gostaria de incorporar relatórios de Power BI com login no meu site para os clientes acessarem. O problema é que o *dashboard* só ira aparecer quando você logar no Power BI com sua conta, mesmo o relatório estando em outro site. No caso os clientes teriam que realizar duas etapas de autenticação, no meu site e no Power BI, queria diminuir para uma etapa de acesso, acessando meu site e automaticamente se autenticando no site do Power BI.

Obs.: Não utilizando o Power BI Embedded.

Estou me baseando nesse [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lxhem09unlY&feature=youtu.be) para o compartilhamento de relatórios em web com *login*.

Isso é possível? Se sim, como eu faria ou qual API eu utilizaria?